# android listview show items on top of other elements

Tags: android, list, android-layout, android-listview, items

I have series of elements in android layout as shown in attached image.
one of the element is searchview and below searchview, there are other elements.
i have written a code to display list items. when i click on searchView, the list items are shown. but i want the list items to be shown on top of /over lay other elements below search view. so when i add "drawSelectorOnTop", list items still not shown on top of other elements.

```
  <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_view"
                style="@style/toolbarText"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/works_in"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:visibility="visible">

            </ListView>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. I have tried. but it is not working. the listview with items not displaying on other elements.

Answer (score 0):

try to set this listview on bottomsheet dialog

Answer (score 0):

In addition to add `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"`, you also need set a Drawable that should be used to highlight the currently selected item.

Two ways:

1. use `android:listSelector` xml attribute.
2. use  `setSelector` method.

And you should create a selector xml in `drawable` folder like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_selected="true"   
         android:drawable="@color/gray" />
</selector>
```

suppose the name of this selector xml file is `my_selector`, then you could do like:

```
your_list.setSelector( R.drawable.my_selector);
```